# Add CSS just to the main content and not to include comments

Tags: 7, theming

I'm theming using the Omega HTML5 starterkit theme on Drupal 7, and I want to add CSS just to the main content region in nodes but not to the comments.

How do I do that? What is the class (or ID) for that?

Comment: Why can't you just use Firebug and look for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

In my own Omega subtheme, which is quite standard, page content with comments has this structure (closing tags omitted for brevity):

```
<article ... class="... node ...">
  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="field field-name-body ...">   (node body)
    <div class="field field-name-... ...">    (another node field I'm displaying)
  <div class="clearfix">     
    <nav class="links node-links clearfix">
    <div id="comments" class="comment-wrapper">
```

So a CSS selector of:

```
node > content
```

would get you all the fields in the content, but not the comments. Or if you just want to style the body, you could choose it specifically.

Note that the `content` class is used a number of different places in a page. Alternatively you might want to set up  some default CSS for most of the node and style the `#comments` or `.comment-wrapper` separately.

This is not profound: I just poked around with Firebug to figure it out.